# Hive cast string to floating decimal

Tags: sql, casting, hive

I am trying to cast a string field with a variable decimal to double. The problem I'm running into is that because the decimal is variable and can be any one of the following:

```
359.879999
35.8799999
3.59879999
```

(move the decimal wherever you want to...but the length of the field is always 9)

I have tried to do:

```
cast(RECURR as float) as RECURR
```

but that is just returning:

```
359.880004882813
```

I have tried:

```
cast(RECURR as decimal) as RECURR
```

and that returns:

```
360
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about trying:

```
select cast(recurr as decimal(19, 9))
```

This should be appropriate for anywhere where the decimal place lurks.

Do note that the unused decimal places will be zeroes.

Comment: The end results are the same as casting it as a float. 

359.880004882813

Comment: that worked after I had changed my Hive to Double from Float. Thanks!